# Center a 2 column table through middle border

Tags: html, css

I have a table like this with two columns of different widths. How do I center the table on the page by the middle vertical border?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1 test</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1 test</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1 test</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For example:

```
                    |  center of page
                    \/
 ------------------------------------------
|                                          |
|   My table                               |
|    -------------------------             |
|   | col 1 test     | col 2  |            |
|   |----------------|--------|            |
|   | col 1 test     | col 2  |            |
|   |----------------|--------|            |
|   | col 1 test     | col 2  |            |
|    -------------------------             |
|                                          |
 ------------------------------------------
```

Comment: The widths are going to be unknown. I'm going to be populating the table

Comment: if the widths are going to be unknown that your question makes no sense. Centering a middle border than might push some right table content out of view

Comment: Now, to avoid other sub-questions, you might want to go [edit] your question and expand it with more info.

Comment: What is wrong with just centering overall? Like `table { margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: Not to sound like everyone else here, but you would need to know your column widths in order to offset the center point.

Comment: @SeanStopnik that's exactly why (removed first comment) i've said that JS could be used (to calculate). But OP simply said that the widths are unknown without adding more details, which than, centering the middle border makes no sense at all cause might push the table behind the left edge. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is some wonky code, but technically works.  I wouldn't exactly suggest using it as is:

http://jsfiddle.net/pq2x4t4f/

```
var columnWidth1 = $('td:first-child').width(),
    columnWidth2 = $('td:last-child').width(),
    offset = (columnWidth1 - columnWidth2) / 2;

$('table').css('right', offset + 'px');
```